Why is Unity Game view still showing only one eye after switched to "Both Eyes" mode?
I encountered a problem when developing a stereoscopic project with HTC Vive Pro Eye and SteamVR on Unity v2022.3.
After start running in the Unity Editor, even if I switched the Game view to Both Eyes, the view still kept a monocular view, although the display actually seen in the HMD was already stereoscopic as expected. I have tried adding
XRSettings.gameViewRenderMode = GameViewRenderMode.BothEyes; 

in my script but it didn't help. See below image

where the difference between eyes is the purple, eye-tracking gaze ray.
Then I found the Project Settings → XR Plug-in Management → OpenVR → Mirror View Mode options which seems to relate, but it didn't provide a Both Eyes option

The Left or Right options only determined whether the Game view keeps at left-eye or right-eye display. The None option would totally shut off the Game view, while the Open VR option seemed to turn the Game view to a mix of both eyes and also impacted the SteamVR preview

Now what can I do to recover the Both Eyes mode in the Game view?
PS.
Interestingly, this project was updated and reconstructed from a lower version of Unity (v2019.4). In that older version, the Game view could display the Both Eyes mode normally

and it even did not have a XR Plugin management package

In all the cases above, the display inside the VR headset was always normal and stereoscopic as intended. The problem was only regarding the Game view.

"Interestingly, this project was updated and reconstructed from a lower version of Unity (v2019.4). In that older version, the Game view could display the Both Eyes mode normally". Not surprising. Unity is known for breaking things that worked when adding newer stuff. Also, while this is not your scenario, there was a ticket posted for a similar issue, except it was for XR on iOS. My point is, it could be a Unity bug so not much you can do other than change the version.

@TheNomad Thanks. Seems nothing I can do so I'll just use the SteamVR preview instead for monitoring. Lucky this is not a core function I need.

If you can easily reproduce the bug, send a MRE to UT via the Report a bug feature from the Editor. It automatically adds all editor logs and project files. You can also add some other files you might find of interest. From my experience, their response time is pretty good as is their bug fix time, especially for game-breaking bugs or regressions. I recommend you do it now as it can take a month or so, in which case, by the time they fixed it, you could use it. Or, as I said, update to a newer (or older?) Unity version.

@TheNomad Nice advice! Totally new to Unity so didn't know much about the technical supports. I'll try reporting the issue and take a chance.
